# Difference between Dir[File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '..', 'lib', '**/*.rb')].each { |f| require f } and $ << File.join(File

Tags: ruby, rspec

Is there any difference between two of these code for spec_helper.rb?

Or practically doing the same things?

```
$ << File.join(File.dirname(FILE), '..', 'lib')
Dir[File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '..', 'lib', '**/*.rb')].each { 
|f| require f }
```

Answer (score 3):

They are not equivalent at all.

`File.join(File.dirname(FILE), '..', 'lib')` does not work. The correct version is `File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '..', 'lib')` which takes the path of the file that line is in and joins them with / (depending on your OS of course) with `'..'` and `'lib'`. So in the end you get a string (nothing more) that is something like `'/location-of-the-file/../lib'`

The second line is a Dir.glob (see http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Dir.html#method-c-glob) based on the input string of `File.dirname(__FILE__), '..', 'lib', '**/*.rb')` (which does again what I describe above). `Dir[string]` results in an array of all the files (just a string nothing more) that match the globbing string. In this case all files (including subdirs) of the lib directory that end in `.rb`. Then the code goes over each of those strings that represent a file and `require`'s it (loading the code into the current file).